# How to encrypt an InputStream with JNCryptor

Tags: java, encryption, inputstream, jncryptor

I'm developing an iPad app and using RNCryptor for the encryption and decryption on the device. There is a Java version of this encryption format available in the form of [JNCryptor](https://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/).

I now have data to be read from an InputStream, but I want to encrypt the data before it is read. I found a class called [CipherInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html), which seems to do exactly what I'm looking for. Only thing is, I need a [Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) (and [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html)) to specify the encryption method, and I don't know how to do that. Is it even possible to define a custom Provider?

Does anyone have suggestions on alternative ways to use JNCryptor for the encryption of an InputStream?

Comment: I will, thanks :)
For now I've written my own code, but it would be nice if there was like an "update" method I could call, instead of having to do everything. I think the only method from the library that I can use now is for keygeneration, haha.

I've posted my solution in an answer to this question, you might be able to use it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up writing a class to read the InputStream, encrypt the data parts at a time, and write to a PipedOutputStream. This PipedOutputStream I then connected to a PipedInputStream, which I eventually returned. The encryption and writing to the PipedOutputStream happens on a separate thread to avoid deadlock.

```
PipedInputStream pin = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pout = new PipedOutputStream(pin);
EncryptionPipe pipe = new EncryptionPipe(5, pout, in, cipher, mac, metaData);
//EncryptionPipe(int interval, OutputStream out, InputStream in
//              ,Cipher cipher, Mac mac, byte[] metaData)
pipe.start();
return pin;
```

And in EncryptionPipe:

```
public class EncryptionPipe extends Thread {
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mac.update(metaData);
            out.write(metaData);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] crypted;
            byte[] hmac;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
                if (bytesRead < buf.length) {
                    //the doFinal methods add padding if necessary, important detail!
                    crypted = cipher.doFinal(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    hmac = mac.doFinal(crypted);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bytes.write(crypted);
                    bytes.write(hmac);
                    crypted = bytes.toByteArray();
                    bytesRead = crypted.length;
                    bytes.close();
                } else {
                    crypted = cipher.update(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                    mac.update(crypted, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                out.write(crypted, 0, bytesRead);
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait(interval);
                }
            }
            out.close();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JNCryptor v1.1.0 was released yesterday and provides support for streaming encryption and decryption.

Use [`AES256JNCryptorInputStream`](http://rncryptor.github.io/JNCryptor/javadoc/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256JNCryptorInputStream.html) to decrypt and [`AES256JNCryptorOutputStream`](http://rncryptor.github.io/JNCryptor/javadoc/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256JNCryptorOutputStream.html) to encrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default Java provider.  To instantiate a cipher you would use

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
```

This uses [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) and [Cipher Block Chaining mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation).  CBC only works on multiples of 16 bytes, so you're also specifying a way to pad your input to multiples of 16 bytes.

[Here is some more sample AES code](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html) to get you started

Comment: So is that the same method of encryption as RNCryptor? Because I will need to decrypt the data on the iPad with that library.

Comment: I looked into it, and I think I should be able to mimic the encryption method of RNCryptor with a Cipher, but I need a specific format for RNCryptor to decrypt it client side. I'm starting to think I might need to read the data into memory and output encrypted data to a piped outputstream or something...

Comment: Or maybe I should just use SSL, doh

Comment: I ended up writing code for streaming encryption based on JNCryptor, since SSL wasn't the solution after all.